# Multiple instances of (this) referring to different elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So I decided to combine multiple html files into a single file, hiding and showing divs instead of linking each page. I also combined all of the different scripts into a single  tag.

However, not all of the code runs anymore - specifically functions referring to "(this)" - is this because it can only be used once per page?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with how you combined your javascript code. Can you provide examples of what used to work, and how you combined it such that it doesn't work now? Maybe we can spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

no. "this" depends on the context of the javascript in question. no combination of JS files will ever affect the context of "this". "this" only has meaning inside of a function or method. placing methods or function next to each other in no way nests them inside of each other.

what is more likely to have happened is a polluted global namespace. if, for example, two files contain a variable named `var link` then whichever code appears later will take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

No. `this` refers to the DOM element invoked. In the jQuery realm `this` is utilised with the jQuery constructor function `$()` to become `$(this)`, which basically lets you utilise jQuery functionality on an invoked DOM element.

I suspect you have some other conflicting issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function to change the `this` scope of any of your functions.